# How can I find out what table is joined with a certain table?

Tags: sql-server

I am refactoring my application and I don't need one of my db tables any more.  I try to delete it but it gives me an error:

> Drop Failed for: 'XYZ'.  Could not drop because it is referenced by a Foreign Key Constraint

How can I find out what other table has a foreign key column to this table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the table in the Object Explore and View Dependencies?

Comment: Someone down-voted me without making a comment.  Please explain? I'm always open to correction.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list here (leave off the where clause if you want a list of all FK constraints in the database):

```
SELECT name, 
  QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id)) 
  + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id))
  + ' references ' 
  + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(referenced_object_id)) 
  + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id))
FROM sys.foreign_keys
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id) = N'XYZ';
```

To generate a drop, you can just say:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = N'';

SELECT @sql = @sql + '
  ALTER TABLE ' + 
  QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id)) 
  + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id))
  + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ';'
FROM sys.foreign_keys
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id) = N'XYZ';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    select * from sys.foreign_keys fk  where referenced_object_id = object_id(<tablename>)
```

Comment: Why `all_objects`? Why do you need a join?

Comment: Bad habit from Sybase I guess.